# Common guide legend between different geom_sf ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I'm plotting a set of different maps individually - not facetted. I'd like to have the guide legend on all the maps that shows the same global range for the data, even though on any one map the whole range for the data may not be shown.

In the reprex below, Plot A shows the global legend for the data but Plot B does not. How can I add a global legend for Plot A?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(spData)

nz_i_class <- nz %>% 
  mutate(income_class = cut(Median_income, breaks = c(22000, 24000, 26000, 28000, 30000, 32000, 34000), include.lowest = T)) 

breaks<-c("22000-24000", "24000-26000", "26000-28000", "28000-30000", "30000-32000", "32000-34000")

# Plot A with global income classes
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = nz_i_class, aes(fill = income_class)) +
  geom_sf(data = nz_height) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(labels = breaks) +
  ggtitle("Plot A")
```

[image: PlotA]

```
# Plot B shows local, not global, income classes
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = nz_i_class %>% filter(Island == "South"), aes(fill = income_class)) +
  geom_sf(data = nz_height) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(labels = breaks) +
  ggtitle("Plot B")
```

[image: PlotB]

EDIT: Added limits as per comment from @stefan. This overrides the polygon fill.

```
# Plot C trying to set limits
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = nz_i_class %>% filter(Island == "South"), aes(fill = income_class)) +
  geom_sf(data = nz_height) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(guide=FALSE) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(limits=breaks) +
  ggtitle("Plot C")
```

[image: PlotC]

Comment: Set the same `limits` for both or all of your fill scales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the legend for multiple plots you could set the same `limits` for each `scale_fill_xxx`. The issue with your code for Plot C is that you have set the `limits` equal to the labels you used for `Plot A`. The chosen labels however are not the labels of your `income_class`es in the data. By default `cut` assigns labels like `(XXX, YYY]` for the intervals. That's why you get a map without any fill colors as the categories of `income_class` are not included in the vector of `limits`. To fix this set the `labels` in `cut` equal to your vector of `breaks`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(spData)

breaks <- c("22000-24000", "24000-26000", "26000-28000", "28000-30000", "30000-32000", "32000-34000")

nz_i_class <- nz %>% 
  mutate(income_class = cut(Median_income, 
                            breaks = c(22000, 24000, 26000, 28000, 30000, 32000, 34000), 
                            labels = breaks,
                            include.lowest = T)) 

# Plot A with global income classes
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = nz_i_class, aes(fill = income_class)) +
  geom_sf(data = nz_height) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  ggtitle("Plot A")
```

[image]

```r
# Plot B with 
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = nz_i_class %>% filter(Island == "South"), aes(fill = income_class)) +
  geom_sf(data = nz_height) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d(limits=breaks) +
  ggtitle("Plot C")
```

[image]